# Is it possible to Import UWP C# DLL in C#?

Tags: c++, dll, uwp, compilation

I made a UWP C# DLL in UWP C#.
Is it possible to Import UWP C# DLL in C#?

Comment: what do you mean by into C#?  Are you looking to use it in a WPF project?  What is in the UWP C#?

Comment: Could you edit your language tags and question text? What parts of this are C++ or C#?